# Override/hide class property inside of another property

Tags: c#, properties, overriding

I want to hide a certain property from the inherited class of another property.

Class I'm inheriting:

```
public class Sensor
{ 
    public Guid ID { get; set; } 
}
```

Another class where the property is inheriting from Sensor:

```
public class TargetDeck
{
   public Sensor TargetSensor { get; set; }
}
```

TargetDeck does not inherit from Sensor, only TargetSensor. I am getting Guid ID conflicts because of the Guid ID in Sensor. My idea was to hide that property for TargetSensor. How can I do this if it is possible?

Comment: Can you provide a more complete code example? Just the class definitions containing only the relevant properties.

Comment: @TimS is that enough above? There are more fields inside of the Sensor class, but the Guid ID is the only one that I want to override in the TargetSensor property.

Comment: What do you mean by override? You are not inheriting from `Sensor`

Comment: Are you saying that when a user has an instance of the Sensor class, and accesses the property sensorInstance.ID, you want to return the ID of the TargetSensor property?

Comment: TargetSensor is of the Sensor type, so it is inherited from Sensor. But I want to override TargetSensor's ID value. @kyriacos_k

Comment: @TimS I want to override TargetSensor's ID value. I am getting Guid ID conflicts from the value where it is conflicting with another Sensor Guid ID.

Comment: public new Guid ID { get; set; } on the TargetSensor class?

Comment: @TimS TargetSensor is a property, not a class. I'm sorry I didn't write it well in my original statement.

Comment: @ShannonMorris I don't think that you understand what [override](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) means.

Comment: Can you please use a different word than `override`? You are using it seemingly incorrectly, and that is making it very hard to understand what you want.

Comment: @Jonesopolis I want to set the Guid ID property in TargetSensor

Comment: You want `TargetDeck` to not be able to access the `ID` property of `TargetSensor`?

Answer (score 0):

Just override the property getter in the subclass.

```
public class TargetSensor : Sensor
{ 
    public Guid ID { 
        get {
            return new Guid("This is your default/overridden property");
        } 
        set; 
    } 
}
```

After reading the most recent comments, this may not be what OP is after.

EDIT: This may be an instance of the [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: This would be helpful if TargetSensor was a class, but TargetSensor is a property. My original post was not very clear. Thanks for your response!

Comment: I see now, if you want that property to have a default ID when it is part of the `TargetDeck` class you can do that in the constructor for `TargetDeck` by setting the property to `new Sensor { ID = "DEFAULT/OVERRIDEEN" }`